# How to move a subvolume to a new drive in btrfs?

Tags: filesystems, opensuse, fstab, btrfs, replace

I am trying to move my /srv, /var/lib/mysql and /home directory to another drive ( a bigger one with RAID1).
I did some research on how to go about doing this and I kind of did most of it.
However, after all the content is copied over, I am unable to replace the new snapshot in new drive as the one to use by default.
Can some kind soul please help point me to the correct direction? Note that step #5 is where I am stuck.

Preparation:

The fstab currently looks like this:

```
    # grep srv /etc/fstab
    UUID=0888211b-2636-4eb5-97da-52679d93a275  /srv                    btrfs  subvol=/@/srv                 0  0
```

The filesystem overall looks like the following. First drive is not raid. Second drive is RAID1

```
# btrfs filesystem show
Label: 'ROOT'  uuid: 0888211b-2636-4eb5-97da-52679d93a275      <-- source drive
        Total devices 1 FS bytes used 16.05GiB
        devid    1 size 40.00GiB used 17.05GiB path /dev/sdd3

Label: none  uuid: 273dbdbd-16d9-4ae4-bde7-d30a48474a44        <-- destination drive
        Total devices 2 FS bytes used 799.20MiB
        devid    1 size 7.28TiB used 2.01GiB path /dev/sda
        devid    2 size 7.28TiB used 2.01GiB path /dev/sdc
```

And the subvolumes list because each drive already has subvolumes

```
# btrfs subvolume list / |grep srv
ID 260 gen 12751 top level 256 path @/srv
# btrfs subvolume list /data-1
ID 258 gen 226 top level 5 path subvol-1
ID 261 gen 225 top level 258 path .snapshots
```

So I did the following steps:

1 created a readonly snapshot of /srv

```
# btrfs subvolume snapshot -r /srv /srv_snap
Create a readonly snapshot of '/srv' in '//srv_snap'
# btrfs subvolume list / |grep srv
ID 260 gen 12784 top level 256 path @/srv
ID 526 gen 12784 top level 267 path srv_snap
# btrfs filesystem sync /
```

2 Send the readonly snapshot to new drive which is mounted as /data-1

```
# btrfs send /srv_snap | btrfs receive /data-1
At subvol /srv_snap
At subvol srv_snap
# btrfs subvolume list /data-1
ID 258 gen 226 top level 5 path subvol-1
ID 261 gen 225 top level 258 path .snapshots
ID 332 gen 227 top level 258 path srv_snap
```

3 Now renamed this readonly copy to desired name and made it read-write

```
# btrfs filesystem sync /data-1
# btrfs subvolume snapshot /data-1/srv_snap /data-1/@srv    
Create a snapshot of '/data-1/srv_snap' in '/data-1/@srv'
# btrfs subvolume list /data-1  |grep srv               
ID 333 gen 233 top level 258 path srv_snap
ID 334 gen 233 top level 258 path @srv
```

4 Removed unnecessary snapshots

```
# btrfs subvolume delete /data-1/srv_snap /srv_snap
Delete subvolume (no-commit): '/data-1/srv_snap'
Delete subvolume (no-commit): '//srv_snap'
```

5 Now I want to replace the /srv partition detail in fstab with the new one via btrfs way. This is where I am stuck

```
# btrfs replace start /dev/sdd3 /data-1 /srv
probe of /data-1 failed, cannot detect existing filesystem.
ERROR: use the -f option to force overwrite of /data-1
```

If it matters, relevant version numbers:

```
# btrfs version
btrfs-progs v5.7 
#cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="openSUSE Tumbleweed"
# VERSION="20200905"
ID="opensuse-tumbleweed"
ID_LIKE="opensuse suse"
VERSION_ID="20200905"
PRETTY_NAME="openSUSE Tumbleweed"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:opensuse:tumbleweed:20200905"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.opensuse.org"
HOME_URL="https://www.opensuse.org/"
LOGO="distributor-logo"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your last step is unclear to me.
I think you have moved your data from btrfs array A to B.

You used to mount the directory with

```
UUID=0888211b-2636-4eb5-97da-52679d93a275  /srv                    btrfs  subvol=/@/srv                 0  0
```

So  you should replace this line in /etc/fstab with

```
uuid=273dbdbd-16d9-4ae4-bde7-d30a48474a44 /srv  btrfs  subvol=/@srv 0 0
```

You need to change the UUID and then reference the subvolume.

The replace command is used to remove disks from an array. I don't really understand what you are trying to do.